# a question on definite integral $\int\limits_0^t e^{\alpha t}\sin(\omega t)\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to find $\int\limits_0^t e^{\alpha t}\sin(\omega t)\,\mathrm dt$. I'd like to know whether it can be brought into some closed form expression. Please suggest me some hints to solve this.

Comment: this should help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/name-of-this-identity-int-e-alpha-x-cos-beta-x-frace-alpha-x-alp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the imaginary part of a similar integral that is easy to compute.

Comment: @Carl: Is the solution $e^{\alpha t}sin(\omega t) + \frac{\omega}{\alpha^2 + \omega^2}$ correct ?

Comment: I get the $\omega/(\alpha^2+\omega^2)$ part, but not the other part. Instead of it, I'm getting stuff like $\omega\cos(\omega t)/(\alpha^2+\omega^2)$ and similar for $\alpha \sin(\omega t)$, with various minus signs.

Comment: My instinct is to do it as the imaginary part of the complex integral $\int \exp(\alpha t + i\omega t)\;dt$, but I see (from the  Chandru1 hint) that you can do it by messing around with integration by parts. That seems messier, but will get the same answer given no errors in the algebra.

Comment: @Carl: I am getting it as $e^{\alpha t} \frac{\alpha\sin(\omega t) - \omega \cos(\omega t) + \omega}{\alpha^2 + \omega^2}$

Comment: @Rajesh D; That is almost what I got, but I also have an $\exp(\alpha t)$. Note that it is zero when $t=0$, as required. When you get the right answer, you can differentiate it to see if you get the thing under the integral in the original question.

Comment: @Carl Brannen : We should consider only the imaginary part of the integral.Is this correct ? please let me know if that is the procedure you have done.

Comment: Yes, after integrating, you take the imaginary part. And I think you did that correctly, but in the algebra, left off the $\exp(\alpha t)$. Oh, now I see it's in there. So never mind!

Comment: @Rajesh; I seem to get $e^{\alpha t} \frac{\alpha\sin(\omega t) - \omega \cos(\omega t)}{\alpha^2 + \omega^2} + \frac{\omega}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}$. This is not quite the same.

Comment: @Carl : Now I am getting the same, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts may help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use $\sin \omega t = \frac{1}{2 i}\left(e^{i\omega t} - e^{-i\omega t}\right)$.