# Orthogonal Trajectory of $x^2 + 2y^2 = k^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

$x^2 + 2y^2 = k^2$

I first take the derivative like the instructions say.

$2x + 4y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

I am not entirely sure why a dy and dx appears but it does in the instructions so I go with it.

Now I need to solve for $y'$

$ + 4y \frac{dy}{dx} = -2x$

$  \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{2y}$

$  \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{2y}$

So now I need to find the inverse negative

$  \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y}{x}$

And that should be my slope at each line.

And now I need to solve that.

$  \frac{1}{2}ydy = xdx$

Take the integratal and I get

$\frac{1}{4}y^2 = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + C$

$y^2 = 2x^2 + C$

$y = \sqrt{2x^2 + C}$

This is wrong and I do not know why.

Comment: After you say "And now I need to solve  that", you have an error. You instead want to say ${dy\over dx}={2y\over x}\Rightarrow {dy\over 2y}={dx\over x}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra I still get the wrong answer that way too though.

Comment: Jordan, you're still going by memorization. It won't work. "I am not entirely sure why a dy and dx appears" seriously suggests that you shouldn't be doing these kinds of problems yet, since you can't seem to recognize the chain rule. More importantly, you have the attitude that you don't have to. If you don't understand something, *ask*. Don't ask for the answer, ask *why*. You'll be better off.

Comment: Some detailed review would've shown you didn't move on with the inverted equation. You should make an effort to look at your solution with care.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff There were just too many variables and things I did not know so I came here to clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the line David noted you; You would have $\frac{dy}{2y}=\frac{dx}{x}$. So by integrating from both sides, you get $\frac{1}{2}$Ln$|y|$=Ln$|x|+c$:
$$\int\frac{dy}{2y}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$ $$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$  $$\frac{1}{2}Ln|y|=Ln|x|+c$$ wherein $c$ is a constant. You can simplify the result as $y=cx^2$.
[image]

Comment: I do not know how to find y from this.

Comment: @Jordan then $\ln |y|^{1/2}=\ln |x| +C\Rightarrow |y|^{1/2}=  |x|\cdot e^C \Rightarrow |y|=C_1 x^2$.

Comment: I forgot that log trick.

Comment: Very cool graphic, and nice work, too +1 ($> 17000$)!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Thanks my friend. The same for you. :)

Comment: @B.S.: (+1) nice answer. I believe this is Maple's plot.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Yes Dr. Thanks for your consideration. :)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding why the $dy$ and $dx$ show up, the short answer is "because of the chain rule." In these situations, we're *trying* to solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, right? That means we're assuming at the outset that $y$ is a function of $x$! You know that $k$ is a constant, here, so $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[k^2\right]=0,$$ which you calculated just fine. Now what if the other side looked like $x^2+2(f(x))^2$? Well, then by the chain rule, we have $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2+2(f(x))^2\right]=2x+2\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left[(f(x))^2\right]=2x+4f(x)f'(x),$$ or, written another way, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^2+2(f(x))^2\right]=2x+4f(x)\frac{df}{dx}.$$ Since in this particular situation, we are assuming $y=y(x)$ is a function of $x$, then applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides gives us $$2x+4y\frac{dy}{dx}=0,$$ **That's** why the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is there.

The only potential problem, here, is that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ may be undefined in some places, so let's look at another way we can deal with that.

---

If instead we simply apply the differential operator $d$ to both sides, the right side would still become $0$, as a derivative of a constant. On the other side, we would have $$d\left[x^2+2y^2\right]=d\left[x^2\right]+2\cdot d\left[y^2\right]=2x\,dx+4y\,dy,$$ so $$2x\,dx+4y\,dy=0.$$ For some more details, refer back to the discussion of the differential operator in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151358/integral-of-int-e2x-sin-3x-dx/155769#155769).

Now, if given a general equation $Au+Bv=0$--with $2$-dimensional coordinates $(u,v)$--for a line passing through the origin, what would be the equation of the perpendicular line passing through the origin? We can't necessarily use a slope-type argument (the line could be vertical, after all), but it is a good exercise to prove that $-Bu+Av=0$ is a general equation for the corresponding perpendicular line, **regardless** of the constants $A,B$.

Here, we have a similar situation, with $u=dx$, $v=dy$--tangent lines can be vertical, after all, as you should be able to see from the level curves in the picture from Babak's answer--so instead of talking about $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x,y)$, we can instead stick with the general form $$2x\,dx+4y\,dy=0\tag{#}$$ of the parallel line through the origin. There are three cases that we must consider, here: (1) $x,y\neq 0$, (2) $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$, (3) $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$. Why needn't we consider the case that $x,y=0$? Because in that case, we are considering the equation with $k=0$, which has only $(0,0)$ as a solution--that is, it isn't a curve, but a point, so we can't really talk about tangent lines in any meaningful sense.

***Case (1)***: Suppose that $x,y\neq 0$. The perpendicular line to $(\#)$ through the origin will then have form $-4y\,dx+2x\,dy=0$, or equivalently $$\frac{1}{2y}\,dy=\frac{1}{x}\,dx,$$ which describes the orthogonal trajectory (OT) curve to $x^2+2y^2=k^2$ at the point $(x,y)$. Integrating yields (as in Babak's answer) $$\frac{1}{2}\ln|y|=\ln|x|+c.$$ Since you've got both $y$ and $x$ "trapped" in natural logarithms, you really want to get them out, and the best (really only) way to do that is through exponentiation. You're trying to solve for $y$, so let's begin by isolating $\ln|y|$, yielding $$\ln|y|=2\ln|x|+2c=\ln(|x|^2)+2c=\ln(x^2)+2c$$ through log rules. Now exponentiating both sides of the equation base $e$, we have $$|y|=e^{\ln(x^2)+2c}=e^{\ln(x^2)}e^{2c}=Cx^2,$$ where $C=e^{2c}$. We're still not quite there, yet, since $y$ is still in absolute value, but it will either be $y=Cx^2$ or $y=-Cx^2$. Thus, the OT curve passing through $(x,y)$ in this case will be of the form either (a) $y=Kx^2$ ($x>0$) or (b) $y=Kx^2$ ($x<0$)--where $K$ (you should see) is in either instance some non-$0$ real constant determined by $x$ and $y$.

***Case (2)***: Suppose $x\neq 0$ and $y=0$, then $(\#)$ becomes $2x\,dx+0\,dy=0$, and the perpendicular is $0\,dx+2x\,dy=0$, or equivalently (rearranging and dividing by $2x$), $dy=0\,dx$. Integration yields $y=c$, and given what we know about $y$, we have $c=0$. Thus, in this case, the OT curve passing through $(x,y)$ is either (a) $y=0$ ($x>0$) or (b) $y=0$ ($x<0$). Note that we can still write this in the form $y=Kx^2$--it is just that $K=0$ in this case.

Hence, we can combine cases (1) and (2), so that if $x\neq 0$, then the OT curve passing through $(x,y)$ has the form either (a) $y=Kx^2$ ($x>0$) or (b) $y=Kx^2$ ($x<0$)--where $K$ is some real constant determined by $x$ and $y$.

***Case (3)***: Similarly to case (2), we find that the OT curve has form either (a) $x=0$ ($y>0$) or (b) $x=0$ ($y<0$). How can we talk about such a curve in terms of curves $y=Kx^2$ ($x>0$) or $y=Kx^2$ ($x<0$)? Well, the one from (a) can be obtained as a limit of such curves as $K\to+\infty$, and the one from (b) can be obtained as a limit of such curves as $K\to-\infty$.

**Remark**: In cases (2) and (3), it should be clear that the $4$ open rays described are the relevant OT curves, if one simply looks at the level curves associated to each $k$. Still, we may find them explicitly as above.

Comment: I do not really understand that link, I mean I follow what is happening for the most part I just do not see the significance of it and how it applies here.

Comment: I have added more details to the answer. Hopefully it is clearer how the link applies, now.