# Integration by parts: $ \int x\cos(x) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$ \int x\cos(x) dx $$

So I just the integration by parts: $\int f(x) \cdot g'(x) dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f'(x) \cdot g(x) dx $

$f(x) = x$ and $g'(x) = \cos(x)$, we get:

$$ x \cos(x) dx = x\sin(x) - \int 1 \cdot \sin(x)dx$$

Here is where the problem starts. I am in doubt as to whether which of the following answer (if any) are correct:

$ x \cos(x) dx = x\sin(x) - -x\cos(x)dx$ (does $1$ turn into $x$?, and if not, why not?)

or

$ x \cos(x) dx = x\sin(x) - - \cos(x)dx$

$ x \cos(x) dx = x\sin(x) + \cos(x)dx$

$ x\sin(x) = 0$? Which must be totally incorrect. Please help me out.

Comment: Your first equality is incorrect, the $1$ does not turn into a $x$, simply because it is a $1$ who multiplies a $\sin$. Your next two  are what you need to do, but your third one is wrong, you seem to have simplified $x\cos(x)-\cos(x)$ to $0$

Comment: But isn't the integral of 1 x?

Comment: See answer underneath

Comment: Oh, nevermind, the 1 would only turn into an $x$ if it was a subtraction or addition, right?

Comment: Note that you can typeset $sin$ and $cos$ with $  "\"sin$. this gives a better result $sin(x)$ compared to $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first couple of steps are correct. Why are you hesitating? Just do the last integral so that your answer becomes $$\int x\cos(x)\text{d}x = x\sin(x) + \cos(x) +C .$$ Why do you think this is wrong? You can always take its derivative to check your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts is definitely the right idea, here. You must be cautious, though, that you don't drop one of the integrations (which I'll deal with in a moment), and that you don't leave any extra differential terms lying about after you've integrated--as you did when you concluded that $\int\sin x\,dx=-\cos x\,dx$ in your second proposed answer (the $dx$ on the right should **not** be there).

Now, you've got $$x\cos x\,dx=x\sin x-\int 1\cdot \sin x\,dx,$$ which is **very** similar looking to what integration by parts should give you, but if you compare this to the general formula, you'll see that you've lost an integration! You should have $$\int x\cos x\,dx=x\sin x-\int 1\cdot \sin x\,dx,$$ or, since $1\cdot\sin x=\sin x$ and you know how to take the indefinite integral of $\sin x$, we get $$\int x\cos x\,dx=x\sin x+\cos x+C.$$ This is similar to the second answer you suggested, but that integration sign on the left-hand side makes a big difference!

For more on how we need to treat differential terms, see the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155769/28900).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful not to do 
$$
\int f(x)g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx\int g(x) dx.
$$
This equality is wrong in most case. Just take $f=g=1$. This is why the $1$ does not turn into a $x$. Using the formula you provide, you get
$$
\int x\cos(x)dx=x\sin(x)-\int \sin(x)dx=x\sin(x)- (-\cos(x))=x\sin(x)+\cos(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$x \sin(x)+\cos(x)$ is the right answer. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%20cos%28x%29).