# Leibniz notation - how to get $dx$ out of a derivative $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$

Tags: notation, derivatives

I know that velocity equals $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ which is writen in Leibniz notation. How can i get $dx$ out of it in a proper way? I don't like it when people say that i should just multiply denominator $dt$ with $v$ like this:

$$
\begin{split}
v &= \frac{dx}{dt}\\
v\, dt &= dx \longrightarrow \boxed{dx = v \, dt}
\end{split}
$$

I think that there must be some rules behind this which aren't mentioned most of the time. So what are these rules? How can i get same result in a proper mathematical way? Could you recommend any good book which focuses only on Leibniz notation and its tricks.

Comment: Expressions such as $dx$ and $dt$ are called *differential forms* (or sometimes just *differentials*).  They always meant to be integrated.  You could start here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(infinitesimal)

Comment: The middle section of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/155769/28900) is related. I see that anorton has already answered similarly, so I won't add another answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that velocity and position functions are functions of time such as $x(t)$ and $v(t)$. By taking an infinitesimal increment of position with respect to an infinitesimal increment of  time we get

$$d\ x(t)=\frac {d\ x(t)}{d\ t}d\ t$$
and by definition of velocity we know that
$$v(t)=\frac {d\ x(t)}{d\ t}$$
which reveals
$$x(t)=\frac {d\ x(t)}{d\ t}d\ t=v(t)\ d\ t$$

Comment: You simply used the definition of differential $d\ x=\frac {d\ x}{d\ t}d\ t$?

Comment: Right. It means an infinitesimal change in x can be calculated by the differantial of x with respect to t multiplied by infinitesimal change in t.

Answer (score 1):

Not one of my best answers, but it is what it is...

It is notation, just like much of math.  Using prime notation, we can define this quantity called the *[differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function)*.  For the below example, the differential is $dx$:
$$dx = f'(t) dt$$

This is why you will see confusion when performing separation of variables.  Really, the $dx$, $dt$, or whatever other variable at the end of an integral is a differential.  That is why we can simplify:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=xt$$
$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=t$$
$$\int\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}dt=\int t\;dt$$
Note that we're realy integrating both sides with respect to t!  However, $\frac{dx}{dt}dt = dx$, based on the definition of the differential.

So, this becomes:
$$\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\int t\;dt$$