# Integral (square root function multiplied by exponential function) did i do it right?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to determine $\int x^3\sqrt{x^2 +1}\, dx$

I said that $u(x) = x^2 + 1$

and then that $dx = 2x\,dx$
so I rewrote the integral as

$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2 +1}\,2x\,dx$$

which is also

$$\int2x^4\sqrt{x^2 +1} \,dx$$

and then it is easy to integrate, is that all legal to do?

Comment: It appears that you started to try a $u$ substitution but then switched to a different plan.  What happens if you complete the $u$ substitution?  Do you have a text you are studying?

Comment: Well I do i have a textbook for my class but this problem is simply one of many practice problems listed in the section we are working on.There's nothing about this problem in the book that i can see... I'm deep into the practice problems were it requires applied knowledge and such, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Try the Maple command [IntTutor](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) which gives hints and shows the required solution step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not. You should not have an equation with a "differential factor" on one side and not on the other (that is, $dx=2x$ is nonsense). For more on how to deal with differential factors, you might find the second part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155769/28900) (from "Now, if I wrote..." through "...let's get back to your problem.") useful.

What you *can* say is that $$\frac{du}{dx}=2x,$$ so that $$du=2x\,dx,$$ so that $$x\,dx=\frac12\,du.$$ Then your substitution gives you $$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac12\int x^2\sqrt{u}\,du.$$ We're not quite there, yet, though. Can you rewrite $x^2$ in terms of $u$?

Comment: yeah, (u-1) then say (u^1.5 - u^.5) thats simple. thanks i need to remember to think things through and actually do the equation for derivatives since i seem to not understand it perfectly

Comment: That's it, yes! By the way, welcome to Math.SE! Just a few quick notes for you. For help formatting your questions (the better the question is formatted, the better the response is, usually), see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and follow the links to the guide. Kudos for putting your thoughts and attempts into your post (that is strongly encouraged)!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int x^{3}\,\sqrt{x^{2} + 1\,}\,{\rm d}x
=
\int x^{2}\,{\rm d}\left[{1 \over 3}\,\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}\right]
\\[3mm]&=
x^{2}\,{1 \over 3}\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}
-
\int{1 \over 3}\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}
\,{\rm d}\left(x^{2} + 1\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 3}\,x^{2}\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}
-
{1 \over 3}\,{\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{5/2} \over 5/2}
=
\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}\left[%
{1 \over 3}\,x^{2}
-
{2 \over 15}\left(x^{2} + 1\right)
\right]
\\[3mm]&=
\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}\,{3x^{2} - 2 \over 15}
\end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\
\color{#ff0000}{\large\quad%
\int x^{3}\,\sqrt{x^{2} + 1\,}\,{\rm d}x
\color{#000000}{\ =\ }
{1 \over 15}\left(3x^{2} - 2\right)\left(x^{2} + 1\right)^{3/2}\
+\
\color{#000000}{\mbox{constant}}
\quad}
\\ \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score -1):

HINT:  when completing a $u$ substitution, the typical flow is as follows:

$$\int x^3\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$

Substitute $u=x^2+1$, then $du=2xdx$ and we have $x^2=u-1$:

$$\int {(u-1)\sqrt u du\over 2}$$

From there, the remaining steps are to integrate, then reverse-substitute to obtain the function relative to $x$, and to add the unknown constant.

Comment: I wish I knew why this answer was down-voted.  I think I have correctly shown the steps up to just before the point of potentially solving the problem for the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Your substitution should be completed by letting
$$\frac12\int (u-1) \sqrt{u}du$$

By using integration by parts, this can be solved.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right... The $2x^4$ term is not available in the original function at all...

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake..