# Trouble with this integration by parts integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int e^{6x}\cos7x \mathrm dx$$

I was trying integration by parts:

$$\int e^{6x}\cos7x \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{7}e^{6x}\sin(7x)-\frac{6}{7}\int e^{6x}\sin(7x)\mathrm dx$$

however I get an equally hard integral on the right.

Comment: Try it one more time!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integral of $\int e^{2x} \sin 3x\, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151358/integral-of-int-e2x-sin-3x-dx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Integrate by parts a second time. The $e^{6x}\cos(7x)$ term will reappear. Rearrange the equation by combining it with the original on the lefthand side.

Comment: Do i have any errors in the first step?

Comment: To @samsamradas: No errors.

Comment: @samsamradas Easy check: when you get your final answer, as a *sanity-check*, take it's derivative.  It should match the function shown in the original integration.

Answer (score 1):

In general,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{b}{a} I+\frac{a}{b} I = & \frac{b}{a} \int e^{a x} \cos (b x) d x+\frac{a}{b} \int e^{a x} \cos (b x) d x \\
= & \frac{1}{a} \int e^{a x} d(\sin b x)+\frac{1}{b} \int \cos (b x) d\left(e^{a x}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{a}\left[e^{a x} \sin b x d x-a \int e^{a x} \sin b x d x\right] +\frac{1}{b}\left[e^{a x} \cos b x+b \int e^{a x} \cos b x\right]+c \\=& \frac{e^{a x}}{ab}(b \sin b x+a \cos b x)+c\\
I= & \frac{e^{a x}}{a^2+b^2}(b \sin b x+a \cos b x)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}I(a,b)=&\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx\\
=&e^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}-\int ae^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}dx\\
=&e^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}-\left(\color{red}{-}ae^{ax}\frac{\color{red}{\cos(bx)}}{b^2}\color{red}{+}\int a^2e^{ax}\frac{\color{red}{\cos(bx)}}{b^2}\right)\\
=&e^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}+ae^{ax}\frac{\cos(bx)}{b^2}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\underbrace{\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)dx}_{I(a,b)}\\
I(a,b)=&e^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}+ae^{ax}\frac{\cos(bx)}{b^2}-\frac{a^2}{b^2}I(a,b)\\
\left(1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)I(a,b)=&e^{ax}\frac{\sin(bx)}{b}+ae^{ax}\frac{\cos(bx)}{b^2}&\end{align}$$
Now its simple to rearrange for $I(a,b)$. Note the same technique will work for:
$$\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)dx$$
Taking advantage of the periodicity of both functions higher order derivatives.