# How to compute $ \int e^{-st} \sin(2t) dt $

Tags: integration

Wolfram Alpha shows me the result of $ \int  e^{-st} \sin(2t) dt $ .
However it doesn't let me see the step to step solution. Then I tried to do this by hand as the solution didn't look "too difficult", however couldn't do it. 
So can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Try writing $\sin(2t)$ in exponential form using Euler's formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name of this identity? $\int e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)  \space dx = \frac{e^{\alpha x} (\alpha \cos(\beta x)+\beta \sin(\beta x))}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19796/name-of-this-identity-int-e-alpha-x-cos-beta-x-space-dx-frace-al)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by using integration by parts two times, and then solve algebraically for the integral you want:

$\begin{align}
\int  e^{-st} \sin(2t) dt  &= -\frac12 e^{-st}\cos(2t) -\frac{s}{2}\int e^{-st}\cos(2t) dt \\
&=-\frac12 e^{-st}\cos(2t) -\frac{s}{2}\left(\frac12 e^{-st}\sin(2t) + \frac{s}{2}\int e^{-st}\sin(2t) dt \right) \\
&=-\frac12 e^{-st}\cos(2t)  -\frac{s}{4}e^{-st}\sin(2t) - \frac{s^2}{4}\int e^{-st}\sin(2t) dt
\end{align}$

So, that's two applications of integration by parts. Now you can add that last term back over to the left-hand side:

$\int  e^{-st} \sin(2t) dt + \frac{s^2}{4}\int e^{-st}\sin(2t) dt = -\frac12 e^{-st}\cos(2t)  -\frac{s}{4}e^{-st}\sin(2t)$

Multiplying everything by $4$ and factoring appropriately, we obtain:

$(4+s^2)\int e^{-st}\sin(2t) dt = -e^{-st}\left(2\cos(2t) + s\sin(2t)\right)$

or,

$\int e^{-st}\sin(2t) dt = \frac{-e^{-st}\left(2\cos(2t) + s\sin(2t)\right)}{4+s^2}$.

Answer (score 6):

You can integrate by parts twice or use this method

$$\int e^{-st}\sin (2t)dt=\operatorname{Im}\int e^{(-s+2i)t}dt$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

using integration by parts we obtain
$\int e^{-st}\sin(2t)dt=-e^{-st}\frac{cos(2t)}{2}-\int\frac{s}{2}e^{-st}\cos(2t)dt$
and now the same once more